# Create a generic function that takes objects but does not take arrays

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I want to create a generic TypeScript function that satisfies this:

```
f({ a: 1 }); // success
f(undefined); // success
f([]); // should fail the type check
f([1, 2]); // should fail the type check
```

In other words, the function should not allow arrays to be passed as the argument, but should take objects.

Problem is, the array is an object in JavaScript. Even this is valid:

```
const x: Record<string, any> = ['test']; // works!
```

So I don't know how I can type the argument or the return type in a generic way so that it takes any object (and also returns it) but doesn't take an array. I want to do it using types rather than at runtime using `Array.isArray`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generic argument constrained to be non array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66745644/generic-argument-constrained-to-be-non-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a [Conditional Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) like:

```
type NotArray<T> = T extends Array<unknown> ? never : T;

function f<T>(arg: NotArray<T>) {

}
```

Will fail for any array type argument

Comment: This breaks if you use generics.: https://pastebin.com/bx83pZLv; do you have any idea how to solve it?