# Generic argument constrained to be non array

Tags: typescript, generics

is there a way to say that passed type argument of a method cannot be an array??

**example class**

```js
class A {
  public f<T /*which is not array*/>(obj: T) { /* ... */ }
}
```

This code would not be compiled:

```js
const a = new A();

a.f<number[]>([42, 42]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```js
class A {
  public f<T>(obj: T extends Array<any> ? never : T) { /* ... */ }
}

const x = new A();
x.f(1) // ok
x.f([]) // error
x.f([1]) // error
```

Btw, there is no negation type in TypeScript. For instance, you can't write smth like: `not Array<any>` or `!Array<any>`, but TS has conditional types.

In my example I'm returning `never` if argument is Array.

What does it mean?

It is mean, that TS will expect one argument with `never` type.

The trick is, that you can't produce `never` type literally.

You can create your own negation type:

```js
type Not<T,  R> =  R extends T ? never: R;
```

Thanks @Eldar !

Comment: Mapped types can be handy : [playgorund](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAcgexAHgCoBoYwEoD4YC8W2MUAHiFAHYAmAzjKjAPwxVQBuUATgFw4BuYKEixEIAILduAQzDIAiviLjkU2fJlUwudEqHAAZgFcqAYxABLBFRiGECRbgAU3GP3Hq5TgJQBvYQBfYXsEZwBtAEYAXR8jBwiAIlDE2PiwyJ8gA)

Comment: @Eldar good point, in this way we can make it more generic.

Comment: @Eldar @captain-yossarian, this was surprising: `type foo = number[] extends NotArray<Record<string, any>> ? true : false` resolves to `true`. Looks like `NotArray` cannot work with `Record<string, any>`, because of the `any`. A non-any Record is fine (`foo` resolves to `false`).

Comment: @AhmedFasih please provide reproducible eample in ts playground

Comment: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAcgexAHgCoBoYwEoD4YC8W2MUAHiFAHYAmAzjKjAPwxVQBuUATgFw4BuYKEixEIAILduAQzDIAiviLjkU2fJlUwudEqHAAZgFcqAYxABLBFRiGECRbgAU3GP3Hq5TgJQBvYQBfYXsEZwBtAEYAXR8jBwiAIlDE2PiwyLiAeiyYACNjEF505GwoMwRuGmQ6EG5LKgBzTC0dFyi0nJgQAAsEY0aetiQZfOooYtDS8srq2vqmzCpjAFs8ngAfeYbGjbyHABsoLQ2AERlKXHaYuKA) link. I'll try to parameterize `Q` to not use `Record<string, any>` to work around this.

Comment: @AhmedFasih from my point of view , using explicit generic parameters along with provided argument is a bad practice. It is justified for fetching data from the server and calling function with empty array - because in these cases TS is unable to infer provided type of array element. From the other hand, `number[]` is nothing more than an object with key and values. Please see [here](https://tsplay.dev/wEvE2N)