# How to declare a type that must be nullable or undefined-able

Tags: typescript

I want to implement a function that accepts a parameter that might be null or undefined. In other words, if the type can't be null or undefined, then it should throw a compilation error. For example:

```js
type A = string | null; // Valid
type B = CustomInterface | undefined; // Valid;
type C = string; // Invalid;
type D = CustomInterface // Invalid
```

My use case is for helper functions such as `assertDefined`, that I don't want them to accept values that will always be defined.

Example ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIFcDOYD2BbASXGniWQG8AoZG5GHHALmRHTwCNoBuSgX0spgAngAcUAQWQBeZNiigA5sgA+LdABt1XZAHodyAGpx1wACaDRKAELS0WXIWKxEKVehCmIMUBFPa9hsZmPMJiaLZyiv76RABuQX4WYQAithjY+ESQzmQBcQkCMO4IYMA4IMhwmJjQYMlePqYAPAAqOgBUEAAekB6YyAD8Q+06AHwAFPHq6BDMLQCUFNS0AQB063wCngjqcFAo6hBglcziPNu7+8iHx+zMVucQO3sHR8gIzKiPz1c3yKbMZI8ShVGpQOoNEC+cZwebRZAAZQAFjgNKZKpocAB3EHVWr1bxQ0zjdhw3T6ZGo9To4zqbG4sEQwnQhBkgKUtEsHDHWn00H4yHQ0xsikozkgbkYuk4oA))

```typescript
function assertDefined<T/*extends ???*/>(value: T) {
    // ...
}

declare let a: A;
declare let b: B;
declare let c: C;
declare let d: D;

assertDefined(a); // Should allow
assertDefined(b); // Should allow
assertDefined(c); // Should not allow
assertDefined(d); // Should not allow
```

Comment: How is that useful? You can always bypass with `let d2: D | null = d; assertDefined(d2) // ok`. Or `assertDefined(d ? d : null)`. Or `assertDefined<D | null>(d)`.

Comment: @Clashsoft It is, because imagine you had a value that was nullable, and you made some extra logic because of it. I'm not really trying to bypass myself. I have used the `assertDefined` example just because it was the simplest example.

Answer (score 4):

You can do the trick.

```js
interface CustomInterface {
    foo: number;
}

type Falsy = null | undefined

type A = string | null; // Valid
type B = CustomInterface | undefined; // Valid;
type C = string; // Invalid;
type D = CustomInterface // Invalid


function assertDefined<T>(
    value: T,
    ...nullable: T extends null | undefined ? [] : [never]) {
}


const a: A = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) <= 5 ? 'a' : null;
const b: B = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) <= 5 ? { foo: 42 } : undefined;
const c: C = 'c';
const d: D = { foo: 42 }

assertDefined(a); // ok
assertDefined(b); // ok
assertDefined(c); // error
assertDefined(d); // error
assertDefined(d, 2); // still error,
```

In order to achieve desired behaviour I used rest operator.

It means that, if `T`  can be either null or undefined `...nullable` evaluates to empty array, which is mean that there is no second argument. Otherwise `nullable` evaluates to 1 element array `[never]`.

But is it possible in this case to pass second argument ?

No! You can't do smth like that in TS. `never` means never :D

So, even if you pass second argument it is still error.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.0-beta#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQGECuBnCB7AWwElJZEVUBvYVW1OPPALlTEwICNYBuYAX2DAIATwAOaAGIIANtmGoAvK0zTpqAD6pMYACZQ44KDsEjxqAIKLUuGOADmG5au6oA9K9QA1GSGOm0AEJWWLiEJNDwyGia2noGYEYu7l4%20Orz%20GFY29kkeJABuqeliaAAiwTj4xKSRFMkFqYJCJagAygAWeCo6AVAAcnhgfSrSCBzSUAA8ACoAfFbTqFAAHtC62E5qMbr6hjqoAPyoiywJ%20TzNZgBKUNgqEFYdXdI9-YPDqmMTk%20azTXDaJAQECDVAIbDYWAQUq7BI6GazAAUNDohWkmCgLGmABoUbQAHSEtifcaY45LVZQdabRyxWFGQ6oADaAF1UCwmWdYCyAJRUfhNJCDXBgliWJQAWQQEHa%20Lg0kYMERUpl%20JgCF0hERfIAVKgAIz6vmTJQAVkZAHIEBb2ZteEKwCKOCwgpLpbL5Yrle61RqdFrdQajagTahzUdKPRGCwACwAJlQfFtdPiiWADpFSBY6CsFqQFvtwoeOhY5SUkYYzFQ8cTgnBkJg0PpOkRCB5uVQeAA1sB61CYamWxx224PN3exD%2083EUgR8lYDA8DAJw2m4PETo5x4F0uV1P1zpsag41vrMDVEsYIuYLjBEA)

Drawback:

```js
assertDefined(d, 2 as never); // valid,
```

Btw, you can find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66745644/generic-argument-constrained-to-be-non-array#answer-66745744) answer useful.
More interesting examples with type negations you can find [in my blog](https://catchts.com/type-nagation) which is dedicated to advanced TS types

Comment: This is really cool. Too bad about the error being a bit strange you get when you try to pass a non-nullable, but hey, it works!

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder . Unfortunately it is not that easy to show custom error messages. We can use branded/tagged literal string for that purpose but not sure if it helps