# Typesafe find on const array in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm wondering if this would be something possible to create a Type-safe `find()` on a const array :

```
const MY_ARRAY = [
  { id: "a", name: "AAA" },
  { id: "b", name: "BBB" },
  { id: "c", name: "CCC" },
] as const;

type MyArrayId = (typeof MY_ARRAY[number])["id"]

function find<ID extends MyArrayId>(id: ID): MyTypesafeArrayFind<ID> {
  return MY_ARRAY.find(entry => entry.id === id);
}

// TODO: here lies the problem :)
type MyTypesafeArrayFind<ID extends MyArrayId> = unknown 

const typesafeResult = find("a");
// I'd expect `typeof typesafeResult` to be { id: "a", name: "AAA" }
// Note: I am *not* interested into something like:
//   { id: "a"|"b"|"c", name: "AAA"|"BBB"|"CCC" }
```

see [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAsgTQPoEEBKaUJgXhgbQCgYYBvGASwBMAuGAIgEN6AaGMRgWwFM76UB9GAF8WxMpVoMARq3ZdeDAEIqho8eWp9gcjjz4BhI2rEBdGIwgxQkKAG5ChKAE8ADt3jOUAJ2+NnAJJUuDAAFC7uIABm8MjomAj4YACunNLc3qYAlPj01PSmjlHJYMBQFOAwURRgVAA8AQAiMNwAHlDctVZwXr7+QQB8oVowTVl0PQAqbtwQjFHcPn7OAGI19U0DZOLe3FDJ3mCxqBhYAHTVtaGdUN7OuFs3d2fUuDh41FkOwo4A9L8wSYAeUaQLoAAsMh4ADYUWYwKCQmCubwgaTQ7icGA0LJOGaeabuOYLJb+Na1BrNNodLqeUmBKhbPAlADWYBAAHcjo4bNAETNidw0LNktDYHhLlRQkx6F9CP9RgByYJtdxlGAAAwi3Gi-KJ8yFIrFGoRIBg6QkIxlbD0in4ghE8oBADkQB06AELFiAFTsqDeyhgDq7aDcYI1KBmiAgHiImoAcxgsJZvCdZxImikMoAPvRZLmdDaFHwBCh6LmVEpy-QjAY1EA)

Do you think this would be something doable for const arrays ?

*As a precision, and even if this is not type-safely expressed in my example, the `id` field in my array will be guaranteed to be unique (we can consider that first entry that matches search criteria will match)*

Thanks in advance for anyone involved.

Comment: Please check [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbQk3N). Does it work for you ?

Comment: Somewhat tough to ctack the nut that is telling Typescript that it will be this specific item of the const array. I'll leave [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAsgTQPoEEBKaUJgXhgbQCgYYBvGASwBMAuGAIgEN6AaGMRgWwFM76UB9GAF8WxMpVoMARq3ZdeDAEIqho8eWp9gcjjz4BhI2rEBdGIwgxQkKAG5ChAGYBXMMCgVwMJxTBUAHgAVNiCAaW4ATxhuAA8obn8rAGsokCcYIIA+AApGJFTIunCotnzGACcKxiKYNG5GKnAAG0iUKprgrLKkADdGZuL8EsjTAEpisnEbaEoEzlwLJErqyIA6X388pAp53Cyl3e5OfHzC8xxLpf7msYcSCiccgEIjzjHScRIoAAsKkAA7uxuECAKJVEAVHIAAwMjDAYBAsE2VDmx2hd3EwnEFW4UBcFTAaM4DmxM1gUEiAAduBBGE5uPUIC5mrA8CicvRqHJEKgMFg2Ex6HcgA) here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have easy to understand solution:

```js
const MY_ARRAY = [
  { id: "a", name: "AAA" },
  { id: "b", name: "BBB" },
  { id: "c", name: "CCC" },
] as const;

type MyArray = typeof MY_ARRAY

type MyArrayId = MyArray[number]["id"]

function find<ID extends MyArrayId>(id: ID): MyTypesafeArrayFind<ID>
function find<ID extends MyArrayId>(id: ID) {
  return MY_ARRAY.find(entry => entry.id === id);
}

type MyTypesafeArrayFind<Id extends MyArrayId> = Extract<MyArray[number], { id: Id }>

// const typesafeResult: {
//    readonly id: "a";
//    readonly name: "AAA";
// }

const typesafeResult = find("a")

const fn = (str: string) => {
  find(str) // error
}
```

However it has it's own cons. You are not allowed to use `find` inside higher order function. You are allowed to use only existing 'ids'.

If you want to make it super safe, and make your co-workers angry, you can consider this solution:

```js
const MY_ARRAY = [
  { id: "a", name: "AAA" },
  { id: "b", name: "BBB" },
  { id: "c", name: "CCC" },
] as const;

type MyArray = typeof MY_ARRAY

type MyArrayId = MyArray[number]["id"]

/**
 * Returns true if provided generic is literal string type
 */
type IsLiteralString<Str extends string> = string extends Str ? false : true

const withTuple = <
  Elem extends { id: string },
  List extends Elem[]
>(tuple: readonly [...List]) => {
  function curry<Id extends List[number]['id']>(id: Id): Extract<List[number], { id: Id }>
  function curry<Id extends string>(id: IsLiteralString<Id> extends true ? Id extends List[number]['id'] ? Id : never : Id): List[number] | undefined
  function curry(id: string) {
    return tuple.find(entry => entry.id === id);
  }

  return curry

}

const find = withTuple(MY_ARRAY)

// {
//     readonly id: "a";
//     readonly name: "AAA";
// }
const typesafeResult = find("a")

let id = 'any id'


const typesafeResult2 = find(id,) // Element | undefined, expected and safe

const typesafeResult23 = find('aa',) // expected error, it is useles to use id which is not exists in our list
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/m36AqN)

`IsLiteralString` - checks whether provided generic is a literal string type or it is just `string`, non infered type.

`withTuple` - expects your list for inference and returns desired function.

`curry` - function which is declared inside of `withTuple` is function with overloadings.

First function overload `function curry<Id extends List[number]['id']>(id: Id): Extract<List[number], { id: Id }>` infers `id` as an existing `id` in our array and infers return type.

Second function overload
 `function curry<Id extends string>(id: IsLiteralString<Id> extends true ? Id extends List[number]['id'] ? Id : never : Id): List[number] | undefined`

Allows you to provide non ifered regular `string` type for higher order function. Also provided `id` is literal and it does not exists in your array, TS will forbid you to use it. I call it "typescript negation". You can find more information about this approach in [my article](https://catchts.com/type-negation) and in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66745644/generic-argument-constrained-to-be-non-array#answer-66745744) answer

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm just discovering Extract (I thought it was kind of a Pick equivalent... but absolutely not ! this is very powerful to query type system !)

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple solution using variadic tuples:

```
const MY_ARRAY = [
  { id: "a", name: "AAA" },
  { id: "b", name: "BBB" },
  { id: "c", name: "CCC" },
] as const;

type MyArrayId = typeof MY_ARRAY[number]["id"];

const find = <V extends MyArrayId>(id: V): MyTypesafeArrayFind<typeof MY_ARRAY, V> => {
  return MY_ARRAY.find(entry => entry.id === id) as MyTypesafeArrayFind<typeof MY_ARRAY, V>;
};

type UnReadOnly<T> = {
  -readonly [K in keyof T]: T[K];
};
type MyTypesafeArrayFind<T extends readonly unknown[], V> = UnReadOnly<T> extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
  ? Head extends { readonly id: V }
    ? Head
    : MyTypesafeArrayFind<Tail, V>
  : never;

const typesafeResult = find("a");
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAsgTQPoEEBKaUJgXhgbQFgAoGGAbxgEsATALhgCIBDRgGhjGYFsBTBxiiGMYAXzYkylWgIBG7Tj35MAQmpHjJFavSbAFXPgIDCpjROIBdGMwgxQkKAG4SJKAE8ADr3juUAJ39mdwBJGlwYD28QADN4ZHRMBHwwAFduWV5-S3xGWkZLF2ISB2gYGKowcLwAHgA1GF4ADyheKrs4P0DgsIA%20AAoZGDqASgZOgBUvXghmGN4AoPcAMUqaGqjeWPjUDCwOOt7cI-Itf14oVP8wHcSsADoKqv62qH93Y8awN-d72lwcHhaCMbB13FNvLN5otgqsqhtpttELskgdekVREU3NMYABVMBoXjMGgAeTAABt3DUJkc8KdSDAALTnYngSkEADS1BuAGteO5thNLAwJvgOYUSJjsd5fBCZnMFt0VmtqY0Wm0aHYWTQ2R9UmAeWAQAB3MD4SxoiL4wnEsmU6lHZqtdoESrzfwwAASRJoHHu-rdWRgE2YVHJli0AH4vT61c7NdptbqdAwGqItGRo97iRmYONwdMoYqlnD1iGw2itAwwLwAG5ZLHEUqwTZFwkQVLk2B4J40fosRgjJxAA)